# Edit fields from a concurrent dictionary

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way were i can edit the fields from a concurrent dictionary like this?

```
Dim UserInfo As New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, String())
UserInfo(myID)(0) = iName
'UserInfo(myID)(1) = Address
UserInfo(myID)(2) = sPhone
UserInfo(myID)(3) = sEmail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods of adding and updating values.

Add and TryAdd or you can use TryUpdate.

For more info try the MSDN link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267291(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks